# hal deploy spinnaker , spin-front50 pod CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: spinnaker

I use hal deploy spinnaker 1.5.1 to k8s 1.6.0 , spin-front50 pod CrashLoopBackOff

**pod status**

this is spinnaker pods status,the front50 is not ok.

```
test-k8s-master00.bj.uc:/home/zhangqiusheng# kubectl get pods -n spinnaker
NAME                                    READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
minio-minio-4189976246-f5qcx            1/1       Running            0          22h
spin-clouddriver-bootstrap-v000-jzb5m   1/1       Running            0          8m
spin-clouddriver-v000-0q0pd             1/1       Running            0          7m
spin-deck-v000-lwchq                    1/1       Running            0          7m
spin-echo-v000-4b397                    1/1       Running            0          7m
spin-front50-v000-wgr8r                 0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   5          7m
spin-gate-v000-jm5db                    1/1       Running            0          7m
spin-igor-v000-4hj25                    1/1       Running            0          7m
spin-orca-bootstrap-v000-s1zbx          1/1       Running            0          7m
spin-orca-v000-27066                    1/1       Running            0          7m
spin-redis-bootstrap-v000-6xjf8         1/1       Running            0          8m
spin-redis-v000-zp52p                   1/1       Running            0          7m
spin-rosco-v000-sxxph                   1/1       Running            0          7m
```

**spin-front50 pod logs**

check the front50 pod logs. I found this log:

`Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 14FCEEE142A960E2; S3 Extended Request ID: null`

detail logs:

```
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386539205Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386544047Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386548497Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.38655264Z   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386556794Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386560857Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386564931Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386568864Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386572991Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386577922Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386582161Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386586356Z  ... 22 common frames omitted
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386590026Z Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 's3StorageService' defined in class path resource [com/netflix/spinnaker/front50/config/S3Config.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.spinnaker.front50.model.S3StorageService]: Factory method 's3StorageService' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 14FCEEE142A960E2; S3 Extended Request ID: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386600484Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386604976Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386609211Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386613461Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386617563Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.38662226Z   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.38662627Z   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.3866305Z    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386634493Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386638519Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386642501Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.38664665Z   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386650695Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386654713Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.38665874Z   ... 35 common frames omitted
2017-12-04T00:10:26.38666236Z Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.spinnaker.front50.model.S3StorageService]: Factory method 's3StorageService' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 14FCEEE142A960E2; S3 Extended Request ID: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386672464Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386677562Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386681671Z  ... 48 common frames omitted
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386685175Z Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 14FCEEE142A960E2; S3 Extended Request ID: null)
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386689307Z  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1587) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.173.jar:na]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386693215Z  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1257) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.173.jar:na]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386697147Z  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1029) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.173.jar:na]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386701103Z  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:741) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.173.jar:na]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386704981Z  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:715) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.173.jar:na]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.38670893Z   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.173.jar:na]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386712881Z  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:665) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.173.jar:na]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386716723Z  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:647) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.173.jar:na]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386720621Z  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:511) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.173.jar:na]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386724435Z  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4227) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.173.jar:na]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386728192Z  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4174) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.173.jar:na]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386731903Z  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1310) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.173.jar:na]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386735767Z  at com.netflix.spinnaker.front50.model.S3StorageService.ensureBucketExists(S3StorageService.java:70) ~[front50-s3-1.118.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.118.0-SNAPSHOT]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386740885Z  at com.netflix.spinnaker.front50.config.S3Config.s3StorageService(S3Config.java:154) ~[front50-s3-1.118.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.118.0-SNAPSHOT]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386749283Z  at com.netflix.spinnaker.front50.config.S3Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$70d0740d.CGLIB$s3StorageService$7(<generated>) ~[front50-s3-1.118.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.118.0-SNAPSHOT]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386754097Z  at com.netflix.spinnaker.front50.config.S3Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$70d0740d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$121232bf.invoke(<generated>) ~[front50-s3-1.118.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.118.0-SNAPSHOT]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386758464Z  at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386762464Z  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386766606Z  at com.netflix.spinnaker.front50.config.S3Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$70d0740d.s3StorageService(<generated>) ~[front50-s3-1.118.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.118.0-SNAPSHOT]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386770933Z  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386774723Z  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386778513Z  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386782328Z  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386785939Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-12-04T00:10:26.386789981Z  ... 49 common frames omitted
```

**storage minio**

I check the minio db . I can login the minio and create test bucket.

**install doc**

```
I follow this install doc : https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/
```

Comment: (Welcome to SO, but:) [What *is* your question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (The second "code block" isn't formatted quite successfully. Be sure to precede it with a blank line.)

Comment: might be https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/2642

Answer (score 0):

1. Install a new halyard version or update it. check the [instructions](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/halyard/#update-halyard-on-debianubuntu-or-macos)
2. Make sure to start with a bad practice AWS IAM permissions for the role with `s3:*`
3. [Upgrade](https://www.spinnaker.io/community/releases/versions/) Spinnaker to newer version